# How to scan for annotations in methods only in specific classes using reflection library java?

Tags: java, spring, reflection, controller, annotations

I have an annotation @API which I assign to all the routes i.e RequestMapping in a controller in java spring.What I want to do is,First scan all the classes in a package that are annotated with @Controller and after scanning all the controller classes,I want only to scan for Methods with annotation @API in only these controller annotated classes.

How can I implement this in using reflection in java?

```
  Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");

  Set<Class<? extends SomeType>> subTypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(SomeType.class);
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/reflections-library will get you started with Reflections. return reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(FunctionalInterface.class); is probably a good start

Comment: Are you using the `Reflections` api of you want to do it without it? If you want without it, the part where you need to get all the classes from a package will not be possible.

Comment: I am using the reflection api

Comment: Have you looked at the [project](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections)'s READ.ME file ? It contains about everything you want to know (annotated classses and methods).

Comment: cant see any similar implementation there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the classes containing the `@Controller` annotation in a package using the reflection api, you can try:

```java
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections
        .getTypesAnnotatedWith(Controller.class);
```

To find the methods that contain the `@API` annotation in a package using the reflection api, you can try:

```java
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
Set<Method> methods = reflections
        .getMethodsAnnotatedWith(API.class);
```

If you want to find methods with `@API` annotation **inside classes that contain only `@Controller` annotation**, you'll need to write code similar to this:

```java
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("my.project.prefix");
Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections
        .getTypesAnnotatedWith(Controller.class);
for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
    Method[] methods = clazz.getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        Annotation[] annotations = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
        for (Annotation annotation : annotations) {
            if (annotation instanceof API) {
                // ..
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a way out!